# TypeORM Cascade only saving the first item of each relation

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

Im making a quiz builder then i have a schema like this:

```
Quiz:
  id: 
  name:
  description:
  --> Questions:
        id:
        name:
        quiz_id:
        description:
        --> Alternatives: 
            id:
            quest_id:
            description:
```

So i have two OneToMany level cascade and i'am facing an issue while trying to save, TypeORM only saving the first item of each relation:

[image: Save Request]

Entities:

Quiz
[image: Quiz]

Questions
[image: Questions]

Alternatives
[image: Alternatives]

I'm expecting TypeORM to save the all items from each relation

Comment: Apologies for the delay, i didn't find any solutions, so... i migrated the entire app to Prisma ORM, and seems to work fine now.